# How to eliminate the indent in reference

Tags: bibliographies, indentation, ieeetran

I'm using IEEE as my referencing style.
Here is the document class of my article

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
```

Then I applied

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,ref}
```

But I got the reference list like this:
[image]
I guess this was caused by the indent of the reference section. Can anyone tell me how to address this issue? Probably adding indents to all the reference lines.

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE. The outcome you're getting is not what would be generated if all default settings were in place. Do please us more about your document setup, beginning with the contents of the document preamble.

Comment: Reference 1 (the WHO reference) has a URL that looks off. It contains the string `diagnostic_imaging`. Apparently it is not marked up correctly as a URL and the `_` sends LaTeX off into math mode. With `IEEEtran` you should use the field `url` to give the URL of a reference. We could say more if you showed us the offending `.bib` entry.

Comment: Thanks for replying me, Mico and moewe. Generally, I changed '_' you mentioned to '\_' in my '.bib' document, the references section backed to normal.  Thanks again. Your advice did work.